# Displaying array as search results?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script that will display search results as an array.  Here's an example of what I'm currently showing as the output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [idx] => 0
        [title] => Stack Overflow
        [description] => A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.
        [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [idx] => 1
        [title] => Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
        [description] => Stack Overflow website logo.png &middot; Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address &middot; stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes.
        [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
    )
```

What I'm wanting to do is display that on a PHP page so that it looks like normal search results.  For the example above, it would look like this:

```
1.  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>
A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.

2.  <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow">Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
Stack Overflow website logo.png &middot; Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address &middot; stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes.
```

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should at least read the php manual before come asking for help, its basic 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the array and access the inner array properties using the keys, note that you should make sure the array is populated, you can use `isset` to check wether a key exists or not:

```
foreach($searchResult as $index => $result) {
  echo $result["idx"] . ". <a href=" . $result["url"] . ">" . $result["title"] . "</a>";
  echo $result["description"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print using following loop -

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
  echo "<div>", $value['idx'], ". ";
  echo "<a href='{$value['url']}'> {$value['title']} </a>";
  echo "<p>{$value['description']}</p>";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: The array shows at `http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=stackoverflow&format=ARRAY` - how do I get the array from that location to display it on my page and use your code?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $result = "";
    foreach($your_array as $key=>$value){
        $result .= $value["idx"] . ". <a href=" . $value["url"] . ">" . $value["title"] . "</a><br/><p>" . $value["description"] . "</p><br/>";
    }
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: The array shows at `http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=stackoverflow&format=ARRAY` - how do I get the array from that location to display it on my page and use your code?  Thank you!

Comment: include that page in your php file as  
<?php include "http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=stackoverflow&format=ARRAY‌​"; ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($your_search_array as $val){
    echo $val['idx']+1.'. <a href="'.$val['url'].'">'.$val['title'].'</a> '.$val['description'];
}
```